# how to use asInstanceOf properly in Scala

Tags: scala

I have been playing with basic Scala data types. I noticed that the `scala.Any` class defines the method `asInstanceOf[T0]: T0` from [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Any) The API has it that it can "Cast the receiver object to be of type T0". Using this method as a starting point, I wanted to investigate casting in Scala. Also, I looked up stackoverflow for other questions on this topic and I came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412068/what-are-the-differences-between-asinstanceoft-and-o-t-in-scala)
With this information in hand, I wrote up a silly program.

```
         package com.att.scala
         import com.att.scala.Sheltie

         object Casting {

             //def foo(x: String){ 
             def foo(x: Int) {
              println("x is " + x)
             //if(x.isInstanceOf[String])
              if(x.isInstanceOf[Int])
                 println("Int x is " + x)
                //println("String x is " + x)
             }

            def entry() {
               //val double: Any = 123.123
               val double: Double = 123.23
               val int = double.asInstanceOf[Int] //exception expected here
               //val str: String = "123"
               foo(int) 
             }

         }
```

---

My goal is to understand what happens (and why) in the following cases:
 1) casting from an Any type to an Int. 
  2) casting from Double type to an Int 
  3) casting from String to Int

1. In the first case, I got a run time ClasscastException as below, when I ran the program as - com.att.scala.Casting.entry. The exception is shown below:

   `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
   at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
   at com.att.scala.Casting$.entry(Casting.scala:17)`
2. In the second case, I get the following result:
   int is 123
   x is 123
   Int x is 123

In this case, the code is supposed to produce a ClasscastException, but it does not. That is my worry.

3. In the third case, I get a classcastexception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(Unknown Source)
    at com.att.scala.Casting$.entry(Casting.scala:20)`

With this example,my goal is to get to the very basics of casting in Scala. I know that this example is not a real world example by any means, but I was trying to get my head wrapped around the basics.

Answer (score 15):

I think you've confused the terms "cast" and "convert".

The standard conversion methods begin with `to`, e.g. `20d.toInt` will convert a value `20` of type `Double` a value 20 of type `Int`.

`asInstanceOf` on the other hand is a special type casting method. All it does is informs the compiler that the value is of the type specified in its parameter, if during runtime the value on which you call this method does not match with  what you specified in the type parameter, you'll get an exception thrown. I.e. in `a.asInstanceOf[B]` the provided value `a` must be of a type `B` or inherit from it - otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Sorry about that unfinished comment. I meant to say that in my program the code - val int = double.asInstanceOf[Int] - is not producing an exception, as it should. Makes sense, because as you said so rightly, we cannot cast Double to an Int, because they are different types. So my concern is: why am I NOT getting an exception

Comment: @ilangogurusamy Hmm.. I reproduced that too. Strange behaviour. I suspect this could be due to the behind the scenes boxing-unboxing magic going on with the primitives.

Comment: Do you think this smells of a bug?

Answer (score 15):

Java (and Scala) allows you to cast a primitive `double` to `int` (in Scala's case, `Double` to `Int`). On the other hand, you cannot cast `java.lang.Double` to `java.lang.Int`.

When you declare the `Double` as an `Any`, you're explicitly asking the compiler to forget that you gave it a `Double`. Therefore, in order to support the `Any` interface, the compiler is storing the value as a boxed double (i.e., `java.lang.Double`).

The behavior does seem confusing, but it's not a bug. According §12.1 of the [Scala Language Spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> The test x.asInstanceOf[T] is treated specially if T is a numeric value 
>   type (§12.2). In this case the cast will be translated to an application 
>   of a conversion method x.toT (§12.2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Just done more tests(compiled and run), I think this may be from one bug of asInstanceOf, it won't do cast.

The last line command gives me **compiling error:**

> Warning:(46, 38) fruitless type test: a value of type Int cannot also
>   be a S
>       println(listTemp2(1).isInstanceOf[S]) // won't compile

```
                                 ^ 

val listOfS = Some(List(S("i1", "k1", "s1"), S("i2", "k2", "s2")))
val listTemp:Seq[K] = listOfS.get.asInstanceOf[Seq[K]]
val listTemp2:Seq[Int] = listOfS.get.asInstanceOf[Seq[Int]]
println("ListTemp:")
println(listTemp(1)) //print S(i2,k2,s2)
println(listTemp(1).isInstanceOf[S])   // true
println(listTemp(1).isInstanceOf[K])   // false
println(listTemp2(1)) //print S(i2,k2,s2)
println(listTemp2(1).isInstanceOf[Int])   // false
println(listTemp2(1).isInstanceOf[S]) // won't compile
```