# Why asInstanceOf doesn't initiate implicit conversion?

Tags: scala, casting, implicit-conversion, implicit

I have a case class with a companion object.
I have implicit conversion method inside the companion object.

```
case class Foo(p:T)

object Foo {
  implicit def Foo2Bar(foo: Foo): Bar = new Bar(doSmth(foo.p))
}
```

I have a method with a param of type `Object`. I want to pass an instance of `Bar` there.
Unfortunatelly, the following code doesn't do the conversion but throws `ClassCastException`:

```
import Foo._
...
val foo = createFoo()
bazz(foo.asInstanceOf[Bar])
```

At the same time, the next (more verbose) code do the job:

```
import Foo._
...
val foo = createFoo()
val bar: Bar = foo 
bazz(bar)
```

Any ideas why the former code doesn't work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412068/what-are-the-differences-between-asinstanceoft-and-o-t-in-scala

Comment: You can just use `bazz(foo: Bar)`. This will trigger the implicit conversion. Note that if `bazz` expects a `Bar` anyway, then `bazz(foo)` is enough as well.

Answer (score 3):

`asInstanceOf` deals only with subtype relationships, but defining an implicit conversion doesn't create a subtype relationship.