# Scala: Casting and Assignment

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema

In Scala/Spark DataFrame

```
    dfReduced.schema.fieldNames
```

is a java String array (String[]). However,

```
    dfReduced.schema.fieldNames.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]]
```

throws

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to
>   scala.collection.Seq

Assigning same array to a Seq[String] is fine.

```
   val f3:Seq[String]=dfReduced.schema.fieldNames
```

As a Java programmer this surprises me as both would require casting in Java. Can someone explain why there is this distinction in Scala

(Note, I'm not being critical, I just want to understand Scala better)

Comment: The difference is `run-time` type cast versus `compile-time` type ascription.  This StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3412235/6316508) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `val f3:Seq[String]=dfReduced.schema.fieldNames` this is working is because In Scala there is implicit conversion available than can cast the `Array[T]` to `Seq[T]` implicitly

In Java there is no such type of implicit casting available.

As `Leo C` mention in comment `The difference is run-time type cast versus compile-time type ascription`. For more info you can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412068/what-are-the-differences-between-asinstanceoft-and-o-t-in-scala/3412235#3412235).

Hope this clears your dough

Thanks