# Scala type mismatch error even after checking type with isInstanceOf

Tags: list, scala, types, typechecking

I have a function `unlist`  taking as first argument a list of any type:

`def unlist(xs: List[Any], ys: List[Any]): List[Any] = ...`

and I call this function on the first element of an external list, which may or may not be a list of lists. Thus, I first need to check if this head element is itself a list, in which case I can call my `unlist`  function.
I do it with `InsintanceOf` method, like so:

```
...
if (xs.head.isInstanceOf[List[Any]]) unlist(xs.head, ys)
```

However, this does not compile because of a type mismatch on xs.head:

```
Error: type mismatch;
found   : Any
required: List[Any]
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**P.S.**: since many of you have suggested to avoid type `Any` , I have to specify that this is part of a coding exercise aiming at having a function as general as possible

Comment: `isInstanceOf` and `Any` are sympton of bad design before

Comment: Result of `isInstanceOf` is NOT being "remembered" and cannot be seen in the next line, as opposed to e.g. pattern matching result within a `case`. I agree with @cchantep though, that this is setting up yourself for a failure.

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate Mateusz's comment

> `isInstanceOf` is not being remembered

it is meant we would have to follow up with `asInstanceOf` like so

```
if (list.head.isInstanceOf[List[_]]) unlist(list.head.asInstanceOf[List[_]])
```

Pattern matching, as demonstrated by Tim, implicitly performs `isInstanceOf/asInstanceOf` combination. Also consider related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3412222/5205022).

If you are unable to refactor out `Any`, which is the **weakest** of types, maybe try to recover as much typing information as early as possible, perhaps like so

```
val lists: List[List[_]] = list.collect { case xs: List[_] => xs }
val ints: List[Int] = list.collect { case i: Int => i }
val strings: List[String] = list.collect { case s: String => s }
```

Note due to **type erasure** we cannot easily do much better than `List[List[_]]`, for example, the following assertion passes

```
val list: List[Any] = List(List("woo", "hoo"), 42, "kerfuffle")
assert(list.head.isInstanceOf[List[Double]])
```

In this last case, a compiler warning will tell you that `type argument Double in type List[Double] (the underlying of List[Double]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. It is usually not a good idea to ignore such warnings.

Comment: Someone might mention `headOption` as safer than `head`: `vs.headOption match { case Some(_: List[_]) => }`. Edit: the OP updated to say it's an exercise in generality.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, using `Any` like this is the sign of some bad design choices. But ***for the specific problem you have***, you can change your `if` to a `match` like this:

```
def unlist(xs: List[Any], ys: List[Any]): List[Any] = ???

val xs: List[Any] = ???

xs.head match {
  case l: List[Any] => unlist(l, ???)
  case _ =>
}
```

The `match` checks that the head value is `List[Any]` then assigns the value to a variable `l` which has type `List[Any]` and can therefore be used in the `unlist` call.

**Note**: This only works because you are testing for `List[Any]`. You cannot test for a list of a specific type (e.g. `List[Int]`) because a process called type erasure removes the runtime information that would be required for this to work. The compiler will warn you when it can't implement a `match` for this reason.

The real solution to this question is to fix the design to use specific types rather than `Any`.

Comment: will not work Exception in thread "main" scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing

Comment: @RamanMishra You need to replace the `???` with the appropriate code.