# Can I avoid using asInstanceOf in a pattern match when matching a stateful subclass object?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, instanceof

As I was modelling expressions like `Var("x")` or `Number(7)` and writing an eval function with pattern matching, I ran into a case where I could not avoid using the ´asInstanceOf` method.

**2 restrictions**

- I do not want to avoid pattern matching by declaring an `eval` method in Expr and define it in its subclasses (cf. Expression problem, I prefer pattern match).
- I also do not want something like `Var("x", 7)`.

```
sealed trait Expr
object Expr {
  def eval(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Number(n) => n
    case Var(_) => e.asInstanceOf[Var].getValue()
  }
}
case class Number(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(s: String) extends Expr {
  var value = 0
  def getValue(): Int = value
  def updateValue(x: Int): Unit = {
    this.value = x
  }
}
```

```
val x = Var("x")
x.updateValue(1)
Expr.eval(x) // 1
```

When I define the second case like this: `case Var(x) => Var(x).getValue()`, i get `Expr.eval(x) // 0`. This is, because `Var(x)` on the right side will construct a fresh `Var` with value `0`.

I'm ok with using `asInstanceOf` but in the sense of improvement, I wonder if there is a cleaner solution than using `asInstanceOf`, which I haven't found yet.

Comment: [Typed pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3412222/5205022) is the preferred style over `isInstanceOf`/`asInstanceOf ` combination.

Comment: I have to say that, mutable case classes are a bad design. And that case classes must always be `final`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@` to bind a variable to a pattern. Use it like this:

```
def eval(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Number(n) => n
    case v@Var(_) => v.getValue()
}
```

You can also check the type of a variable in a pattern match

```
def eval(e: Expr): Int = e match {
    case Number(n) => n
    case v: Var => v.getValue()
}
```

Comment: @colorblind oh ok, yeah. First I apologize if I sounded too imperative, it should have been more of an suggestion like: _" if this solves your problem, please consider accepting this answer"_. - Second, you can always change your mind an accept a different answer if you feel someone gave a better one. Third, being honest, given that yours was a quite basic question with a simple answer, it is improbable there will be a new one, so accepting it now makes sense. cheers :)

Comment: @colorblind probably you already see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) but just in case. And yes, comments are temporary, if they were already useful, we usually delete them, like in this case. Happy coding and welcome to the SO community.