# Scala autoboxing and Java Map

Tags: java, scala, autoboxing, scala-java-interop

I have a Java method takes an argument of type `Map<Long, Foo>`. I am trying to write a unit test for that method in Scala 2.8.1 and pass in a literal `Map[Long, Foo]`.

My code looks like this:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
x.javaMethod(asJavaMap(Map(1L -> new Foo, 2L -> new Foo)))
```

The compiler is giving me the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.Long,Foo]
required: scala.collection.Map[java.lang.Long,Foo]
```

I also tried it with

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
x.javaMethod(Map(1L -> new Foo, 2L -> new Foo))
```

and

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
x.javaMethod(Map(1L -> new Foo, 2L -> new Foo))
```

and got the error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.Long,Foo]
required: java.util.Map[java.lang.Long,Foo]
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says that Scala map with `scala.Long` key type cannot be implicitly converted to Java map based on `java.lang.Long`:

```
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[scala.Long,Foo]
required: scala.collection.Map[java.lang.Long,Foo]
```

As a workaround, you may specify the required type manually:

```
x.javaMethod(asJavaMap(Map((1:java.lang.Long) -> new Foo, (2:java.lang.Long) -> new Foo)))
```

Comment: I did not know that syntax. Learn something new every day. Thanks.

Comment: Is that syntax new? I just looked in a couple of Scala books and could not find it.

Comment: The technique is called `type ascription`, it's not new. You can find some details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascription-in-scala

Comment: I cannot find anything on it in any of my Scala books (Odersky et al, Wampler et al, or Loverdos et al). Thanks.