# What is "Shadowed Implicit Value Members" in Scala doc?

Tags: scala

There is a *Shadowed Implicit Value Members* section in [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) doc. E.g.:

> def split(arg0: String, arg1: Int): Array[String]
>
> **Implicit information**
>       This member is added by an implicit conversion from StringOps to String performed by method unaugmentString in scala.Predef.
>
> **Shadowing**
>       This implicitly inherited member is shadowed by one or more members in this class.
>       To access this member you can use a type ascription:
>
> ```
> (stringOps: String).split(arg0, arg1)
> ```
>
> *Definition Classes*
>       String

But when I try to run following program:

`"aaa bbb ccc".split(" ", 2)                     //> res0: Array[String] = Array(aaa, bbb ccc)`

Calling the `String.split(arg0: String, arg1: Int)` doesn't need using *type ascription* as in the doc described.

So what is the *Shadowed Implicit Value Members* referring to? I tried to ask google but cannot find any reference.

Is it something like:

```
class A {
  def foo() = println("foo")
}

class AOps(a: A) {
  def bar() = println("bar")
  def foo() = println("new foo")
  def foo(i: Int) = println("foo %d".format(i))
}

object Program {
  implicit def A2AOps(a: A) = new AOps(a)         //> A2AOps: (a: A)AOps

  val a = new A()                                 //> a  : A = A@15669ae
  a.foo                                           //> foo
  a.bar                                           //> bar
  (a: AOps).foo                                   //> new foo
  a.foo(1)                                        //> foo 1
}
```

Then the `String.split(...)` and `StringOps.split` function signatures are different, so there will no need be "type ascription".

Is this what "Shadowed Implicit Value Members" stands for? I'm a little puzzled. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally the Scala compiler will look to perform implicit conversions when you call a method that doesn't exist for a given type:

```
case class Foo(x :String)

implicit class Bar(foo: Foo) {
  def barOnly = "w00p"
}

println( Foo("test").barOnly )
```

Here when we call the method `barOnly` on an instance of `Foo` the scala compiler can see it needs to do an implicit conversion from `Foo` to `Bar` to provide us with that method and we get the expected output of `w00p`. [Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/526d69e2e4b0b1a1c4dae50a)

However if a method with the same signature exists in `Foo` and `Bar`, then we have some shadowing and the scala compiler will not do the implicit conversion unless we explicitly ask for it with type ascription:

```
case class Foo(x :String) {
  def whoAmI = "Foo: " + x
}

implicit class Bar(foo: Foo) {
  def whoAmI = "Bar: " + foo.x
}

println( Foo("test").whoAmI )
println( (Foo("test"): Bar).whoAmI )
```

The output is:

```
Foo: test
Bar: test
```

[Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/526d689be4b0b1a1c4dae506)

In your example of `split` in the scaladocs, there are methods called `split` on both `String` and `StringOps`, however they take different argument types, so I'm not entirely sure why the docs are warning us about having to use type ascription. We do not need to disambiguate anything for the compiler in this situation and type ascription has no effect:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.StringOps

val stringOps: StringOps = "aaa bbb ccc"

println( stringOps.split("a", 2).mkString )
println( (stringOps: String).split("a", 2).mkString )
```

The output for these two lines is identical:

```
aa bbb ccc
aa bbb ccc
```

[Try it](http://www.scalakata.com/526d66bae4b0b1a1c4dae4f0)

Maybe just an error in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

"aaa bbb ccc" *is a String object*, not a StringOps object, so the comment is not relevant.

This is a corner case where you would probably never create a StringOps object explicitly, only ever relying on implicit conversions, so this Scaladoc comment seems kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

The scaladoc is telling you about non StringOps methods that you can call on a StringOps instance.  Invoking this method will trigger an implict conversion from a StringOps to a String.

We hardly ever work with raw StringOps objects so the implicit conversion is unlikely in practice.

Type ascription is explained [in this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascription-in-scala)

```
scala> val so=new scala.collection.immutable.StringOps("aaa bbb ccc")
so: scala.collection.immutable.StringOps = aaa bbb ccc

scala> so.split(" ",2)
res8: Array[String] = Array(aaa, bbb ccc)

scala>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like type ascription is necessary when you have an implicit class that overloads the method with a different signature. This is in conflict with what the other answers above are saying.

Take the `apply` method of `TreeMap`, for example. Say I want to overload this with a method that takes a zero-indexed integer position, so I can index into `TreeMap` as if it was an array:

```
 implicit class MapIndexerExtension(m : TreeMap[Double,String]) {
   def apply(idx : Int) = m.take(idx + 1).last
 }

 val m = TreeMap( 0.3333333 -> "A third",
                  2.71828 -> "Natural E",
                  3.142 -> "Pi")              //> m  : scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[Double,String] = Map(0.3333333 -> A 
                                              //| third, 2.71828 -> Natural E, 3.142 -> Pi)

 m(3.142)                                     //> res0: String = Pi
 (m: MapIndexerExtension)(2)                  //> res1: (Double, String) = (3.142,Pi)
 m(2 : Int)                                   //> java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 2.0
 m(2)                                         //> java.util.NoSuchElementException: key
```

You'll note that the last lines fail. What is happening here is that 2 is being converted into a double, and then looked up with `TreeMap.apply`, and of course it fails. This happens even though we are ascribing it with `: Int`
*res1* is ok though, as we are using type ascription on `m`.

In the example in the answer by Theon, you can't see any difference between StringOps and String call to `split`, but I think this is because they are meant to produce the same output, even if they are implemented differently.

Why this happens, I don't know. It's pretty confusing if you ask me; but I think it's to discourage people from doing what I showed in the above example.

Comment: "...but I think this is because they are meant to produce the same output, even if they are implemented differently."
This is because calls the same method defined in the class `java.lang.String`. `StringOps` has no `split(arg0: String)`