# Why does this compile and what is happening?

Tags: scala

I was writing a wrapper class, that passes on most calls identically to the root object and I accidentally left the full definition (with parameter name x, etc) see below. To my surprise, it compiled. So what is going on here? Is this similar to assigning to root.p_ ? I find it strange that I can leave the name "x" in the assigment. Also, what would be the best (fastest) way to pass on wrapped calls - or maybe it makes no difference?

```
trait A {
  def p(x:Int) = println("A"+123)
}

case class B(root:A) {

  def p(x: Int): Unit = root.p(x:Int)  // WHAT HAPPENED HERE?
}

object Test extends App {
   val temp = new A{}
  val b = B(temp)
  b.p(123)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is type ascription, and here, it is not much.

The code works just as if you had written

```
def p(x: Int): Unit = root.p(x)
```

as you intended. When you write `x: Int` in the call (not in the declaration, where it has a completely different meaning) or more generally `expr: Type`, it has the same value as `expr`, but it tells the compiler to check that the expr is of the given type (this is a check made a compile type, sort of an upcast, not at all a runtime check such as `asInstanceOf[...]`) and to treat it has having that type. Here, x is indeed an Int and it is already treated as an Int by the compiler, so the ascription changes nothing.

Besides documenting a non obvious type somewhere in the code, type ascription may be used to select between overloaded method:

```
def f(a: Any) ...
def f(i: Int) ...

f(3) // calls f(i: Int)
f(3: Any) // calls f(a: Any)
```

Note that in the second call, with the ascription, the compiler knows that `3` is of type `Any`, less precise than `Int`, but still true. That would be an error otherwise, this is not a cast. But the ascription makes it call the other version of `f`.

You can have a look at that answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087356/754787

Answer (score 0):

Are you delegating the implementation of `B.p` to `A.p` ?

I don't see any unusual except for `root.p(x:Int)`, you can save typing by `root.p(x)`.

trait is a way of code mixin, I think the easiest way is:

```
trait A {
  def p(x: Int) = println("A" + x)
}

case class B extends AnyRef with A

val b = B() 
b.p(123)
```

Comment: thanks, my example was just to demonstrate a larger piece of code.