# What is the syntax behind this statement?

Tags: scala

I found this statement:

```
var o = None: Option[String]
```

that you can use to set o to a None, with a view to later maybe setting it to a Some[String]

But how does this actual statement break down syntactically? None is an object that extends Option[Nothing] - but how does the rest of the statement work? For example, what does the colon do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In scala, you can follow any expression with a type ascription.  Like `1: Int` is totally valid.  So it's really:

```
var o = (None: Option[String])
```

The purpose is to tell the compiler that that `None` should be typed as an `Option[String]`, so that `o` isn't typed as `None.type`.  Basically, in this example, it's the same as:

```
var o: Option[String] = None
```

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087356/247985

Comment: Ah fantastic - thank you! Just starting out and trying to get to grips with all the colons and things. This really helps! Thanks again..

Comment: I became a fan of ascriptive typing because of partial functions, where the type really gets verbose. `val x = { case something => } : PF[etc,etc,]`. With function literals you needs parens: `val x = (a => b) : Function1[etc,etc].`

Comment: In my opinion, a more readable way to write this same assignment is `var o = Option.empty[String]`

Comment: The implementation of that is just `def empty[A] : Option[A] = None`, so it's the same thing, but the reader has to click through or memorize what that method does. IMO it's better to "inline" a method when calling the method would be longer than the method body.