# Why they did that in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here is my discovery. I've found that in `Scala` I can simply write such expression:

```
val n: Int = (((2: Int): Int): Int): Int
```

and it'll 100% valid. But I have no idea why Scala creators did that? What is the point of this semantic? And are there some reasons for that kind of weirdness?

PS

I can assume that such approach is used for `type inference` to help compiler figure out what is going on. Or maybe there are some other cases?

Comment: This is valid C++ too: int n = ((int)((int)((int)((int)2))));

Comment: Yeah, the same stuff in Java `int n = (int) (int) (int) (int) 42;`

Comment: Seems in Scala it is just a kind of Java legacy. And they just can not getting rid of it.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, it's just that type annotations can be attached to any expression.

Comment: I don't understand why you think such an expression should be invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer

1. Yes, the syntax is valid.
2. What you are doing is called "**type ascription**", telling the compiler what type you expect out of an expression. (see [What is the purpose of type ascriptions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala) )
3. Where do you see any problems? An`Int` (`2` in your case) is an `Int` (and stays an `Int`). Even if you repeat that multiple times via `( (previous : ...) : Int )` it still stays an Int.