# Scala Array[String] to Java String varargs

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I have some Scala code that needs to call a Java 7 method that is defined as follows:

```
public void addListener(InputListener listener, String... mappingNames) {
    <details omitted here for brevity>
}
```

Here is my Scala code that call `addListener`:

```
inputManager.addListener(myListener, getActionInputs())

// Then the getActionInputs method:
def getActionInputs() : Array[String] = {
  Array("Red", "Fruit", "Cow")
}
```

This yields a compiler error:

> Type mistmatch, expected: String, actual: Array[String]

I tried importing the Java/Scala conversions classes to convert my Scala `Array[String]` to a Java array, but have not been successful. Any ideas as to what the fix is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `:_*` to transform the `Array[String]` to varargs:

Java:

```
public class C {
    public void addListener(String... mappingNames) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mappingNames));
    }
}
```

Scala:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val c = new C
  c.addListener(Array("a", "b", "c") :_*)
}
```

Yields:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Comment: Isn't that only for Scala varargs?

Comment: It appears you're right. I don't think that always used to be the case. Is this new since 2.12?

Comment: @Jasper-M I ran this on 2.11.8

Comment: Yes, it seems to have always been like that. Now I wonder why I thought it wasn't...

Comment: @Jasper-M The oldest I found is a forum question from 2010 with Scala 2.8.0 claiming this works.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalItzchakov (+1), does this magical `:_*` construct have a name? Would like to read up on it...

Comment: @smeeb The specification names this [repeated parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#repeated-parameters) (*) and this goes along side [type ascription](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala) (:_).