# None type in Priority queue scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm using a priority queue to order a case class called TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic

```
  case class TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A](parent:Option[TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A]],
                                           action: Option[A],
                                           state: S,
                                           cost: Double,
                                           estimatedRemainingCost: Double)
```

This priority queue is created inside a function that uses its parameter to set the initial state while the other values have to be kept as None or 0

```
  def HeuristicGraphSearch[S,A](problem: ProblemWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A]) = {
    val root = TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic(parent = None,action=None,state=problem.initialState,cost = 0.0, estimatedRemainingCost = 0.0)
    val frontier : mutable.PriorityQueue[TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A]] = mutable.PriorityQueue.empty[TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A]]
    frontier.enqueue(root)
```

However because parent and action are none I get a mismatch between expected type `TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,A]` and the one I'm trying to enqueue `TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S,Nothing]`.

As far as I know Nothing is a subtype of Option and in my case class both parent and action are options. Why am I getting the mismatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's related to the way Scala compiler infers types. Short answer is to simply help it out a bit by explicitly declaring the types when constructing your case class:

```
val root = TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S, A](parent = None,action=None,state=problem.initialState,cost = 0.0, estimatedRemainingCost = 0.0)
```

Reason why `TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S, Nothing]` is not considered a valid substitute for `TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S, A]` is because it's not its subclass; to be one, it would have to be covariant in type A. If some `Foo[A]` is covariant in its type `A`, only then the following holds: `Foo[S] <: Foo[A]` for any `S` that is subclass of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to sloucs answer, you can also use [type ascription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala) to help the compiler out:

```
val root = TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic(
    parent = None: Option[TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S, A]],
    action = None: Option[A],
    state = problem.initialState,
    cost = 0.0,
    estimatedRemainingCost = 0.0)
```

The reason the compiler is complaining is that it has no way to guarantee `None.type` *is a* `Option[TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic[S, A]]` and `Option[A]`, respectively, and thus it "bails out" and infers `Nothing`, which is the bottom type of all types.

@Dima also suggests using `Option.empty[A]`:

```
val root = TreeNodeWithCostAndHeuristic(
    parent = Option.empty,
    action = Option.empty[A],
    state = problem.initialState,
    cost = 0.0,
    estimatedRemainingCost = 0.0)
```

Comment: I'd rather use `Option.empty` - looks a little nicer than type ascription here: `action = Option.empty[A]`

Comment: @Dima You might be right, I'm not sure which one I like more. I'll add both.