# Autocasting types using 'value: Type' syntax

Tags: scala, ascription

When I am reading [Scala reflection tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html). I found a syntax very wired as follows.

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  typeOf[List[_]].member("map": TermName)
```

So the `member` function takes `Name` type parameter, and then `"map": TermName` is passed into it. What does this syntax exactly mean? I am guessing it is sugar shortcut for `.member(TermName("map"))`.

Comment: `obj : Type` means view the object as that type, you may think of it like `obj.asInstanceOf[Type]` but, first it is type safe, and second it is more powerful, for example, in this case it triggers an **implicit conversion**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for a quick reply. Do you know any reference talking about this syntax?

Comment: it should be somewhere in the [specs](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/).

Comment: @kevin Type ascription is mentioned in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax is called [type ascription](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html#ascription):

> Ascription is basically just an up-cast performed at compile-time for
>   the sake of the type checker.

It is used here because the signature of [`member`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/4854c5d4896a0e75de3e19655d0735d274574ccf/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Types.scala#L147) is

```
def member(name: Name): Symbol
```

so it is expecting input of type `Name` hence

```
typeOf[List[_]].member("map")
```

gives error because `"map"` is not `Name`. Providing [type ascription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala) `"map": Name` triggers implicit conversion

```
typeOf[List[_]].member(stringToTermName("map"): TermName)
```

however the same can be achieved with more explicit

```
typeOf[List[_]].member(TermName("map"))
```

The implicit conversion [`stringToTermName`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/ba9701059216c629410f4f23a2175d20ad62484b/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Names.scala#L49) technique is deprecated

```
  /** An implicit conversion from String to TermName.
   * Enables an alternative notation `"map": TermName` as opposed to `TermName("map")`.
   * @group Names
   */
  @deprecated("use explicit `TermName(s)` instead", "2.11.0")
  implicit def stringToTermName(s: String): TermName = TermName(s)
```