# Dyamically cast spark dataframe to dataset of tuple(String,_<:Product)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have encountered a peculiar issue while working with spark, I am not quite sure what is going, would be great if someone can help. My problem is have a function similar to the one below, that is casting dataframes to datasets of sometype, that is decided in runtime. I need to work with Datasets, because the underlying case classes have some annotations that i would like to use.

```scala
 def ret(spark: SparkSession, dss: DataFrame, typ: String): Dataset[_ <: Product] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    typ match {
      case "t1" => dss.as[T1]
      case "t2" => dss.as[T2]
    }

  }
```

I am able to cast a dataframe to dataset with the following function call `val ds = ret(spark,dataframe,"t1")`

Everything works well with this function, now i want to extend the existing function to return a `Dataset[(String,_<:Product)]` so i modify my function like this,

```scala
 def ret(spark: SparkSession, dss: DataFrame,typ: String):Dataset[(String,_ <: Product)] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    typ match {
      case "t1" => dss.as[(String,T1)]
      case "t2" => dss.as[(String,T2)]
    }
  }
```

This gives me a compile error saying, type `(String,T1)`, does not match expected type `(String,_<:Product)`. What is actually happening here? any ideas how I can fix this? Any hints would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!!

**Update:** The upper bound <: Product refers to scala.Product and T1,T2 can be any case classes for exampple,

```scala
case class T1(name: String, age: Int)

case class T2(name: String, max: Int, min: Int)
```

But it can be really anything

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of T1, T2 and Product?

Comment: @ijayadeep thanks for your comment, done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common supertype of `Dataset[(String, T1)]` and `Dataset[(String, T2)]` is not `Dataset[(String,_ <: Product)]` but the more complex [existential type](https://kubuszok.com/compiled/kinds-of-types-in-scala/#existential-types)

```
Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product }
```

`Dataset[(String,_ <: Product)]` is also really an existential type, but a different one; it's a shorthand for

```
Dataset[(String, T) forSome { type T <: Product }]
```

Note that to use `Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product }` without warnings, you need to add `import scala.language.existentials` (and that these types will be [removed in Scala 3](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/proposal-to-remove-existential-types-from-the-language/2785)).

EDIT: I thought that what I checked would be enough, but apparently type inference fails here and I really don't understand why.

```
def ret(spark: SparkSession, dss: DataFrame, typ: String): Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product } = {
  import spark.implicits._
  typ match {
    case "t1" => dss.as[(String,T1)]: (Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product })
    case "t2" => dss.as[(String,T2)]: (Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product })
  }
}
```

*does* compile as expected. You can extract a type alias to avoid duplication:

```
type DatasetStringT = Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product }

def ret(spark: SparkSession, dss: DataFrame, typ: String): DatasetStringT = {
  import spark.implicits._
  typ match {
    case "t1" => dss.as[(String,T1)]: DatasetStringT 
    case "t2" => dss.as[(String,T2)]: DatasetStringT 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, but i still get a compile `Error:(70, 114) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_1] where type _1 >: (String, T1) with (String, T2) <: (String, Product with Serializable)
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product }
Note: _1 <: (String, Product), but class Dataset is invariant in type T.
You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5)
  def ret(spark: SparkSession, dss: DataFrame, typ: String):Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product } = {` any idea what i might be doing wrong here?

Comment: This is because the Dataset API is invariant. Which means that if Something is invariant then even if A is a subclass of B then Something[A] is not a subclass of Something[B]. If you can explain the usecase of what you are trying to achieve there might be other ways of implementing it as you would not be able to modify Dataset API

Comment: @jjayadeep Yes, but `Dataset[(String, T)] forSome { type T <: Product }` is not a `Dataset[Something]`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - Yes correct. I was just trying to explain invariance to the OP. I was also having trouble understanding why the type system fails here and I had to do something similar to what you have posted as edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alexey and ijayadeep, just so that i actually understand what is happening here,  ` dss.as[(String,T1)]:: DatasetStringT ` what does this statement mean? You are casting dss.as[(String,T1)] to DatasetStringT or is it a hint for the compiler ?

Comment: The statement means that the pattern match returns a `type DatasetStringT` which has been defined above. It is not casting but a way to ensure that the code complies with the type system.

Comment: @SaiKiranKrishnaMurthy as jjayadeep says. It can trigger implicit conversions as well, but doesn't here. The technical term is "type ascription" and you can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087250/what-is-the-purpose-of-type-ascriptions-in-scala

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it!! :)